# Excel pivot table - how to sort strings as numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

My row data has numeric values as strings so of course it sorts as strings. How can I force it to sort as numbers?  It seems I can't use a formula in the pivot table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the pivot tables in Excel are very underwhelmingly underpowered. I would recommend creating an new row in your data table and convert the strings to numbers there then use that new row in the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround might be to copy your pivot table and "paste special as values" to a new sheet. Then you can convert them to numbers or use formulas.